# SNS/SQS Size limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

According to the doc, the maximum size for sns/sqs is 256KB but in their extended client the limit is 262144.  Why is this?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/large-message-payloads.html

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sns-java-extended-client-lib/blob/fa50a9298b06b28052e74120f1addb78cb90399a/src/main/java/software/amazon/sns/SNSExtendedClientConfiguration.java#L8C1-L9C1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

256KiB is 262144 bytes.

i.e. 256 * 1024 bytes.

It's fairly common to see KB and KiB used interchangeably. It's confusing,but a part of programming.

Comment: Oh right, forgot about the extra 24 bytes.   Thank you!